# Send and Receive Stream with TidTCPClient and TidTCPServer in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

In Delphi XE2 I have a record type with the following structure :

```
  TMachinInfoRec = record
    IPStr: string[15];
    Username: string[50];
    Computername: string[100];
    SentTime: TDateTime;
    HasCommand: integer; 
    ClientCommands: array[0..9] of TMachineCommand;
  end;
```

I define a variable on its and TMemoryStream variable on the Client side and send stream with TidTCPClient component:

```
var
  MIRec: TMachinInfoRec;
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;

begin
  MIRec.IPStr = '192.168.100.101';
  MIRec.Username := 'user-a';
  MIRec.Computername := 'Computer-a';
  MIRec.SentTime := Now();

  idTCPClient.Host := '192.168.100.138';
  idTCPClient.Port := 6000;

  idTCPClient.Connect;

  msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create;
  msRecInfo.Write(msRecInfo, SizeOf(Client));

  msRecInfo.Position := 0;
  idTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(msRecInfo);
end;
```

and And get information on the server side with TidTCPServer :

```
procedure TFrmMainServer.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  MIRec: TMachinInfoRec;
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
begin
  msRecInfo:= TMemoryStream.Create;

  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msRecInfo, SizeOf(MIRec));

  msRecInfo.Read(msRecInfo, sizeOf(MIRec));

  ShowMessage(MIRec.IPStr);
  ShowMessage(MIRec.Computername)
end;
```

But a string that is displayed in this format:

> MZ?.........yy..,.......@...................................,....

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: When moving record structures between different processes or during I/O, declare the record with the `packed` directive. Otherwise there might be alignment problems. I'm not saying this is the case here, but it can be a potential error later.

Comment: Don't forget to reset the stream's `Position` back to 0 after calling `ReadStream()` and before calling `Read()`. Alternatively, use `TIdMemoryBufferStream` instead of `TMemoryStream` to let Indy read/write your record variables directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
     msRecInfo.Write(msRecInfo, SizeOf(Client));
```

be

```
     msRecInfo.Write(miRec, SizeOf(miRec));
```

Same for read:

```
     msRecInfo.Read(miRec, sizeOf(MIRec));
```

Note that there are several other uncertain factors with this code:

- what is "client"? OTOH, with the above corrections, this is eliminated.
- We can't confirm from this code that TMachineCommand is not a pointer type